# apt-get update/upgrade fails on fresh image

Tags: apt

I've created a fresh SD card with the weezy 2014-6-20 image. And follow [these](http://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/raspbian/updating.md) instructions to update.

So after the freshly created image boots, I issue:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

And this is the result:

```
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 unable to securely remove '/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci': Read-only file system
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 unable to securely remove '/var/lib/dpkg/reassemble.deb': Read-only file system
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/multiarch-support_2.13-38+rpi2+deb7u3_armhf.deb (--unpack):
 cannot access archive: No such file or directory
Processing triggers for man-db ...
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 unable to flush updated status of `man-db': Read-only file system
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
pi@raspberrypi ~ $
```

What can I possibly be doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out I needed to expand the file system to make space for the updates..